# Burninate the [drupal] tag

Tags: discussion, status-declined, burninate-request, migration, blocklist-request

I would like to suggest to burninate [drupal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drupal) tag as its wiki suggests:

> Drupal is an open source CMS framework written in PHP. Consider posting your question directly on https://drupal.stackexchange.com instead of using this tag.

I think that we should migrate all valid answers from this tag to  https://drupal.stackexchange.com: this tag serves no purpose on Stack Overflow as it has its own dedicated website.

Currently it has 13,926 questions and it is a lot, so help from the mods would be great.

Comment: We also have [tag:Ubuntu], [tag:WordPress], [tag:database], [tag:blender], [tag:cryptography], [tag:raspberry-pi], [tag:linux], [tag:tex], etc. despite all of those having their own sites.

Answer (score 36):

**No.**

Drupal questions which involve programming are still perfectly on-topic here and there's no reason to migrate anything that's not off-topic. The tag is still a completely valid tag. The fact that a Drupal SE site exists doesn't mean anything to us.

Comment: then why does drupal exist? well i think yes you have a point, but if its about drupal why not post it directly to drupal SE? isn't that the point of the tag wiki itself?

Comment: The Drupal SE site has a broader scope of what kinds of questions concerning Drupal can be asked. *Here* we only allow programming questions, and any programming questions which happen to involve Drupal are on-topic.

Comment: well can you post programming question in drupal SE? if yes then why not post all of the question there? as it is the main purpose of the site it is also the meaning that is written on the WIKI. yes you have a point that it is valid in SO, what im telling is that it should be placed where it should belong. not just because it is about programming it should be on SO, drupal was made to answer questions concerning drupal and drupal questions should be in drupal as it was made to accomodate questions about drupal.

Comment: The tag wiki should never have been phrased in that way - I've fixed that. It is perfectly possible for Stack Exchange sites to have overlapping scopes, and in that event the user is free to choose whichever community they want to post their question. **We only migrate things that are off-topic.** Period. These questions are not off-topic here, and thus this tag will not be burninated. If a user wants to post on Stack Overflow, then by all means they can.

Comment: Thank you for changing the tag wiki as it contributes in the confusion,

Answer (score 0):

I disagree. The mere fact of a separate site existing for this does not prove that it's off-topic. There are [numerous cases](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/556/how-to-decide-where-to-post-questions-that-are-on-topic-for-multiple-sites) where questions may be on-topic at multiple sites; that doesn't prove that it's wrong for both sites to have the same tag.

It's possible to write legitimate, on-topic programming questions about this framework. It's also not a Meta tag, and is unambiguous. That being said, this doesn't really meet burnination criteria.